# Is there any Java MultiMedia Conversion Library

Tags: java

I wonder if there is a lib, like Apache Commons, or something of that sort to help convert media-files (e.g. avi, mkv, mp4 etc) any-to-any? For example an InputFile is in format .avi and an OutputFile is in mp4.

Comment: Please do not copy/paste the articles and try to demonstrate some code to convert from one to another format. I presume nobody whants a 'Google man' as a respondent. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only library I know for that is [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), but you will have to run it through JNI.

Answer (score 6):

See either of the following to convert between a range of formats.

- [Jffmpeg](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/) is a plugin that allows the playback of a number of common audio and video formats. It is based around a Java port of parts of the FFMPEG project, supporting a number of codecs in pure Java code. Where codecs have not yet been ported, a JNI wrapper allows calls directly into the full FFMPEG code.
- [Xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/) - A free open-source library for Java developers to uncompress, manipulate, and compress recorded or live video in real time.